# Best Android games for long flights

Tags: android, game

I've never posted here so hopefully this is a valid question, but free to close if not.

I've been doing more flying recently, and am often bored on planes.  I've never really been a video game person, but would love some recommendations for good games to play while on a plane.  I have a very recent OnePlus 9 Pro phone running latest Android OS.  I'm really up for any game, since I'm not a gamer I don't really know what I like.  Some games I've been into in the past are Guitar Hero, Halo, Plants vs Zombies (I literally stayed up all night playing that once), empire building games (Warcraft II, Age of Empires, etc), and various puzzle games like Reversi, Bejeweled, etc.  I'm not into violent or shoot 'em up games (Maybe not totally true since I did mention I liked Halo)

Some requirements:

- Obviously must work offline with no Internet
- I don't want to get sucked into "pay to play" things with microtransactions and in-app purchases.
- I don't mind paying under $10 bucks, but I'd just like to pay once and be done, I don't want any sort of recurring fee.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got any answers to this, but I ended up getting [Pocket City](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codebrewgames.pocketcitygame) and [Monument Valley 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ustwo.monumentvalley2).  Both are really good!

Comment: That is two answers.  Please post them separately so that thay may be voted upon separately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).